# There was no endpoint listening at "Address" that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I receive an error on a server when trying to connect to a WCF service.
There was no endpoint listening at "Address" that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

```
<endpoint address="URL-HERE/PF.QUEUE.API.Queue.svc/SOAP" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IQueue" contract="PFQueue.IQueue" name="BasicHttpBinding_IQueue" />
```

I can browse the the URL without any see the Webservice without any problems.

The Webservice is on another server which I can connect to using the same connection string in a config running the same code locally.

I also have a MVC .Net app that uses the same WebService using the exact same endpoint binding which works fine?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  It was a proxy setting in IE that was causing it, for another program being run on the same server.

I added my URL and Port to the Proxy exceptions and its now working